# Edit existing XML file tree

Tags: c#, xml

I have problem with an editting existing xml file. I was looking for a solution but I can not find solution which I need. Can someone help me please?

Here is my code:

```
private void referenceToXML(string path)
{
    var filePath = path;
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);

    var parentElement = new XElement("Items");
    var firstNameElement = new XElement("Item");
    firstNameElement.SetAttributeValue("name", question.text);
    var lastNameElement = new XElement("Cathegory", SM.text);

    parentElement.Add(firstNameElement);
    firstNameElement.Add(lastNameElement);

    var rootElement = xmlDoc.Element("ItemCollection");
    rootElement.Add(parentElement);

    xmlDoc.Save(path);


}
```

And here is result of the code:
**https://pastebin.com/LKGJER38**

But I need this:
**https://pastebin.com/RRC75pR8**

I will appreciate every help.

Comment: It's likely easier to answer if you show the differences. It would help if you describe what the code should do.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I forgot that.

Comment: I have an xml file which storage questions and Cathegory of them. I want to add more questions to xml file by code. The code I posted worked but It creates "Items" elements and I need to create only "Item" elements into "Items" and "Items" element have to be in "ItemsCollection" Element. It might be a chaos to understand this and I am apologize for it but I don't know how to explain it better in English.. :x

Comment: No need to add a "tag" (C#) in your titles; the official tags you add will bring help.

Comment: Can you please share the input XML?  Preferably by editing your question and including it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Add to the Items Element instead :

```
private void referenceToXML(string path)
{
    var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(path);

    xmlDoc.Element("ItemCollection").Element("Items").Add(
        new XElement("Item", new XAttribute("name", question.text), SM.text));

    xmlDoc.Save(path);
}
```

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
AddQuestion.referenceToXML (System.String path) (at Assets/AddQuestion.cs:56)
AddQuestion.addQuestion () (at Assets/AddQuestion.cs:33)
UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall.Invoke (System.Object[] args) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/UnityEvent.cs:154)

Comment: @JustBill you should probably handle the case when the XML doesn't have Items Element, and use VS debugger to find the issue if possible

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are unconditionally adding an `<Items>` element every time you add an `<Item>` element.  Instead, you need to check whether such an element exists, and if so, use it.  The following [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) makes that easy:

```
public static partial class XNodeExtensions
{
    public static XElement GetOrAddElement(this XContainer container, XName name)
    {
        if (container == null || name == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var element = container.Element(name);
        if (element == null)
            container.Add(element = new XElement(name));
        return element;
    }
}
```

Now you can modify your `referenceToXML` method to use it as follows:

```
private static void referenceToXML(string path, string questionText, string smText)
{
    AddItem(XDocument.Load(path), questionText, smText).Save(path);
}

static XDocument AddItem(XDocument doc, string questionText, string smText)
{
    var firstNameElement = new XElement("Item");
    firstNameElement.SetAttributeValue("name", questionText);
    var lastNameElement = new XElement("Cathegory", smText);
    firstNameElement.Add(lastNameElement);

    // Get or create the root element ItemCollection
    var root = doc.GetOrAddElement("ItemCollection");
    // Get or create the Items list
    var items = root.GetOrAddElement("Items");
    // Add the item
    items.Add(firstNameElement);

    return doc;
}
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHkjTk).

Note I modified your code to make `question.text` and `SM.text` arguments instead of class members for clarity and testing purposes.

Comment: I tried your code but .GetOrAddElement is not working it appears red. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry! it working now. I just replace .GetOrAddElement with .Element and it working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JustBill - *I tried your code but .GetOrAddElement is not working it appears red. Do you know why?* - In that case, please share a [mcve] showing the *initial* XML.  Since your question doesn't include the initial XML I used the required output XML from https://pastebin.com/RRC75pR8 as the initial XML in my demo fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHkjTk (which works), but apparently it is not equivalent.